# Cannot compile an example from TikZ manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here it is (from page 604):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text effects along path,
text={text effects along path!}, text align=center,
text effects/.cd,
character count=\i, character total=\n,
characters={evaluate={\c=\i/\n*100;}, text along path, text=red!\c!orange},
character widths={text along path, xslant=0, yscale=1}}]

\path [postaction={decorate}, preaction={decorate,
text effects={characters/.append={yscale=-1.5, opacity=0.5,
text=gray, xslant=(\i/\n-0.5)*3}}}]
(0,0) .. controls ++(2,1) and ++(-2,-1) .. (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why it does not compile, can someone help? My TeX Live is fully updated.

The log reports:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/evaluate', to
>   which you p assed '\c =\i /\n *100;', and I am going to ignore it.
>   Perhaps you misspelled i t.

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: The `evaluate` key requires `\usetikzlibrary{math}`. If I add that to your example, it compiles without error.

Comment: @PaulGessler I thought "calc" was enough, thanks, works. I wonder why they don't include complete MWEs in the manual...

Comment: Yes, it's a nuisance that the dependencies are rarely listed with the examples, but it's because the manual has loaded all the libraries already. You can usually find the required libraries by searching for the key causing the errors as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `evaluate` key is a part of the Tikz `math` library. I found this by searching the manual for `evaluate=`; the definition is on p. 648 of the v3.0 manual.

Add `math` to the list of libraries loaded, and the example compiles without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,decorations.text,calc} % added `math' here
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text effects along path,
text={text effects along path!}, text align=center,
text effects/.cd,
character count=\i, character total=\n,
characters={evaluate={\c=\i/\n*100;}, text along path, text=red!\c!orange},
character widths={text along path, xslant=0, yscale=1}}]

\path [postaction={decorate}, preaction={decorate,
text effects={characters/.append={yscale=-1.5, opacity=0.5,
text=gray, xslant=(\i/\n-0.5)*3}}}]
(0,0) .. controls ++(2,1) and ++(-2,-1) .. (3,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]